# add class of tag to another tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have class to h4

```
h4
{
   color:red;
}
```

I want h2 to contain the class of h4

```
h2
{
   h4
}
```

is it possible? 
I need to do it or in the css or in the jquery

Comment: just a note: That's not a class, that's a CSS rule for a tag. A class is something which you add as an attribute to a tag in HTML and for which you set up a seperate CSS rule in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a CSS related issue. It is as simple as indicating two different selectors for the same declaration, like this:

```
h2, h4 {
  color: red;
}
```

Now, the `color:red` applies to both h2 and h4.

**Edit:**

If you want to apply the rules defined for the `h4` to your `h2` but do not have access to the CSS or do not want to modify it, you can do it through Javascript. To do so, you need to get the styles of the h4 and, for example, create a new rule that applies to h2 in the same page. Here you have an example:

https://codepen.io/davidballester/pen/XeREqO

The ideas here are: getting the styles with `window.getComputedStyle` and creating a new rule, in my example, inside a custom style element dynamically appended to the HTML.

Comment: I dont have the style of the h4. I need to change only the style of h2

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want your h2 to look like the default styles of the h4?

Comment: he want to ref styles not assigned

Comment: I mean that I dont have access to the style of the h4